# What plots should be used for diagnostics for linear mixed model?

Tags: r, mixed-model, random-effects-model, diagnostic

Before fitting a linear mixed model, can any plots be used to show a random intercept/slope is justifiable in the model? I.e. these plots may indicate a different pattern for each individual over time.

After fitting a linear mixed model, what diagnostics can be performed to see if any model modification is needed?

Comment: Usually a choice between a fixed and random intercept (or slope) would be based on characteristics of the situation, not on the data values.

Comment: Why? Isn't random intercept(or slope) used to describe the difference in baseline(or rate) between individuals?

Comment: Sure, but differences will occur for a variety of reasons, including just by random variation (noise makes the individual estimates differ even when their population values may not). One might use fixed effects to account for intercept or slope differences in some particular situations, or simply treat the variation as part of the overall error in other cases. Often the consideration is *a priori*, rather than *post hoc*, and arguably should usually be so.